# Encrypt decrypt issue with new php version

Tags: php, encryption, php-5.3, mcrypt, php-5.6

I have a encrypt function on one of my website which is running on PHP 5.3.29
The function works proper on this version of PHP. The function is:

```
function encrypt($text) { 
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)))); 
}
```

I have another website which is running on PHP 5.6.29. The same function does not return anything on this version. It returns blank.

Similarly I have decrypt function which is also not working on PHP 5.6.29

```
function decrypt($text) { 
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))); 
}
```

I need to make this function to work on PHP 5.6.29 as my websites are connected via API. I have no idea how I can make this to work. Any help please?

Comment: Deconstruct your function calls and see which one is not returning the expected result.  Ex. try just base64_decode, just mcript_get_iv_size, ...  This way once you find which one you can look it up in the documentation and see what changed.

Comment: Wouldn't the `mcrypt_create_iv` used in `mcrypt_decrypt` create a new IV instead of using the one that the original text was encrypted with? Also running `trim` on the encrypted string can potentially remove data necessary to recreate it.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes it would. But ECB mode doesn't utilize IVs; they're ignored, no difference if you provide them at all. That's also why ECB is bad.

Comment: @Narf, I am sorry but I guess I am not able to explain myself. Actually I haven't stored the SALT value in database. I mean to say that I have stored the passwords and other important stuffs in database using the above function. I have a global variable which has as value for SALT and I use that global variable where ever needed. Can you please give a little explanation on what do you mean by "correct value" of SALT?

Comment: @YunusAslam I [meant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015825/encrypt-decrypt-issue-with-new-php-version?noredirect=1#comment80981016_47016047) that it's not a salt; it's an encryption key - different terms with different meanings, and different requirements to use them properly.

Comment: @YunusAslam Also, there's a ton of issues within the little code you've shown, but from your last comment it looks a lot like you're entirely on the wrong track with this. User passwords must be *hashed*, not encrypted like you're doing - again, different things.

Comment: @Narf again I am sorry. I am not hashing passwords. I am storing card details in database using the above encrypt function. I have got this working using 32 character SALT.  The old card details I have saved using 27 characters SALT in the previous php version 5.3.29. So the old encrypted values which are stored in database are no longer working with 32 characters on the new php version 5.6

Comment: Getting the old values is easy and @iainn's answer already tells you how to do that by quoting the manual ... It's just that you obviously don't have enough knowledge to even understand it. I could give you a one-liner that solves that one small problem, but there's a ton of other issues and if you're storing payment cards data, this is no pet project. Hire a professional, because as it is you shouldn't be allowed to process payments at all.

Comment: @Narf I got that working. Thank you for your support. I am not very new  in PHP, its just that few things take a little time to understand.

Comment: @YunusAslam Conversation is long enough already, so this is my last comment, but I have to say this: This here has very little to do with PHP and a lot to do with security, cryptography - entire fields in their own right. You can be a PHP guru and still know almost nothing about cryptography (that is perfectly fine and very common), and that's why you need to hire someone who does understand it. What is NOT ok is handling sensitive data when you don't know how to do it, because that puts your customers at risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably passing an incorrect value for SALT. From the manual:

> Invalid key and iv sizes are no longer accepted. mcrypt_encrypt() will now throw a warning and return FALSE if the inputs are invalid. Previously keys and IVs were padded with '\0' bytes to the next valid size.

This was a change made to PHP 5.6, which lines up with what you're seeing.

Note that an encryption key is not the same as a hashing salt, which can generally be of any length.

Comment: @ianin I have a correct value of salt. I have stored the values  in database using the above encrypt function and now I am unable to do it on the newer php version. I need to do that any how. Do you have any idea how to make that work?

Comment: You cannot, by definition, know that you have the "correct value" as long as you're calling it "salt". Because it's not a salt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with SALT. If you will give 32 character SALT then these functions will give output in PHP 5.6.29 as well.